# The cardano-wallet docker compose always connects to testnet?

Tags: wallet, cardano-node, docker

I'm running the docker compose from iohk for `cardano-wallet` (https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).

I execute the compose using the following command:

```
NETWORK=mainnet docker-compose up
```

Now when I hit the api to check the status, it tells I'm in the byron era:

Request

```
curl http://localhost:8090/v2/network/information
```

Response

```
{"node_era":"byron","node_tip":{"height":{"quantity":67669,"unit":"block"},"time":"2017-10-09T13:50:11Z","epoch_number":3,"absolute_slot_number":67696,"slot_number":2896},"sync_progress":{"status":"syncing","progress":{"quantity":1.03,"unit":"percent"}}}%
```

Shouldn't I be in the current era? I assume I am connected to testnet since it is still on byron. I haven't modified the docker compose and see no other way to specify mainnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that your Cardano node is not done syncing and it is just in the Byron era of the blockchain history.

You can see the current height (read: the number of blocks in the chain) being just `67669`. When you look at the explorer, that is just block from [2017/10/09 13:50:11 UTC](https://explorer.cardano.org/en/block?id=99957c52f7d4e73ac616c47e802bb383d5d84a649266379b064ab9982f544891).

Give it time and make sure it is completly synced and on the tip with the rest of the blockchain.

Also, to clarify, the testnet is also on Alonzo era.